# Does Polymer use a synthetic DOM like React?

Tags: dom, polymer, reactjs

I've been loving working with Facebook's React. One of the features I love is the synthesized DOM that allows tons of elements without bogging down mobile browsers. Anyone know if Polymer also uses a non-browser dom, or has that as an option?

I could take a shot at combining the two, using React to build Polymer, but that sounds like a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

A principle of Polymer is to *use the platform*. In this case, this means it uses the real DOM at all times.

IMO, it's not true that DOM inherently bogs down mobile platforms; it's all a matter of how it's used.

Other frameworks and libraries have clever systems, and it's great to have choices. But Polymer's specific strategy is to put the work back into DOM via Web Components.

Comment: I'm just asking because most of these html based mobile frameworks are nearly unusable on actual mobile devices. (I'm on iteration 4 of a very simple app.) React seems to do the trick without breaking a sweat. Since the functionality of React is the same as the WebComponent in Polymer, it would be nice to be able to plug it in. (The semantics are way off, though. It would be a tough task.)

Comment: Polymer is supposed to be able to make good mobile apps. Where we fall down, we are looking for reports, so we can try to address those places. Attaching an entirely other system that does very similar work is probably not a good choice. Having said that, you should be able to use Polymer elements _inside_ of React, because Web Components are regular elements, this is also part of the design.